# Run NPM script from neighbouring directory but retain current working directory

Tags: node.js, npm

Lets say I have a setup like this:

```
/FolderA
    index.js <-- console.log(process.cwd())
    package.json

/FolderB
```

I can run the FolderA script from FolderB like so:

`C:\FolderB: npm run start --prefix ../FolderA`

But how would I set this up so the FolderA script would retain FolderB as the working directory?

Essentially I want to run the code from FolderA as if it was sitting in FolderB

Comment: To half answer my question `npm link` WOULD be an option, but I want to achieve this same effect over a network drive.

It seems npm link isn't designed that way

Answer (score 0):

My half answer led me to the full answer, which was simply using windows symbolic links to "relocate" the path of the scripts.

It's not the ideal scenario but it worked out.